# Is there a way to get an approximation of $\det( \sigma_s^2A+B)^{1/N}$ in the GLRT?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, matrix-equations, statistical-inference, signal-processing

Both $A_{N \times N}$ and $B_{N \times N}$ are symmetric Toeplitz matrix, $\sigma_s^2$  is a constant.

In detection theory, the computation of $\det(\sigma_s^2A+B)^{1/N}$ arises in the computation of the GLRT (sometimes referred to as *sphericity test*). In particular, $A_{N \times N}$, $B_{N \times N}$ and $\sigma_s^2$ represent the covariance of received signal, the noise covariance and the received signal power, respectively.

I need to find how $\det(\sigma_s^2A+B)^{1/N}$ varies as $\sigma_s^2$ varies. An approximated expression or bound could work.

Using the Minkowski determinant inequality i found a bound $$\det(\sigma_s^2A+B)^{1/N}\ge \sigma_s^2\det(A)^{1/N}+\det(B)^{1/N}$$ However this inequality yields a not sufficiently tight approximation.

A tight bound or (better an approximation of the above determinant) can be found, maybe under specific conditions on the matrix A and B?

Comment: By GLRT, do you mean "generalized likelihood ratio test"?

Comment: One idea: you might find it helpful to consider the logarithm
$$
\log \det(\sigma_s^2 A + B)^{1/N} = 
\frac 1N \log\det(B + \sigma_s^2 A) = 
\frac 1N \operatorname{trace} \log(B + \sigma_s^2 A)
$$

Comment: Another idea: you might find it helpful to consider a Taylor expansion.
$$
\det(\sigma_s^2 A + B)^{1/N} = 
\det(B)^{1/N} + \frac 1N \det(B)^{1/N}\operatorname{trace}(B^{-1}A) + O(\sigma_s^4)\\
= [1 + \frac 1N \operatorname{trace}(B^{-1}A)] \det(B)^{1/N} + O(\sigma_s^4)
$$

Comment: Yes, GLRT stands for generalized likelihood ratio test.

Comment: I don't see the difference between your correction and what I wrote

Comment: Thanks @BenGrossmann. The second idea could be useful, but if $\epsilon \simeq 0$ the Taylor expansion should be, in my opinion, $f(\epsilon)= f(0)+\epsilon f'(0) +o(\epsilon^2)$ in our case  $\mathrm{det}( I + \epsilon A )^{1/N} = 1 + \frac{\epsilon}{N}\operatorname{trace}(A)^{1/N-1} + o(\epsilon^2)$.
Since i compute $\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\det(I+\epsilon A)^{1/N}=\frac 1N \operatorname{trace}(A)^{1/N-1}$, hence the final relation becomes (for $\sigma_s^2 \simeq 0$)
$\det(B+\sigma_s^2 A )^{1/N} =  \det(B)^{1/N} + \frac 1N \det(B)^{1/N}\operatorname{trace}(B^{-1}A)^{1/N-1} + o(\sigma_s^4)$

Comment: Your computation for $f'(\epsilon)$ is incorrect. For one thing, you incorrectly apply the chain rule to get the derivative for $\det(I + \epsilon A)^{1/N}$

Comment: Ok, thanks i figured out that it was a mistake. So the chain rule applied to $\det(I + \epsilon A)^{1/N}$ yields simply $ \frac 1N \operatorname{trace}(A)$?

Comment: Yes, that's the right answer for $f'(0)$

Comment: Ok, so finally we have $\det(B+\sigma_s^2 A )^{1/N} =  \det(B)^{1/N} + \frac 1N \sigma _s^2 \det(B)^{1/N}\operatorname{trace}(B^{-1}A) + o(\sigma_s^4)$, correct?

Comment: You've forgotten the $\sigma_s^2$ in the second term, but otherwise that's right. I've written it out in detail in case that helps.

Comment: Also, instead of $o(\sigma_s^4)$, it should really be $O(\sigma_s^4)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full computation for the derivative of
$$
f(\epsilon) = \det(B + \epsilon A)^{1/N}.
$$
Let $g(\epsilon) = \det(I + \epsilon B^{-1}A)$, so that $f(\epsilon) = \det(B)^{1/N}g(\epsilon)^{1/N}$. By the chain rule, we have
$$
f'(\epsilon) = \frac 1N \det(B)^{1/N} g(\epsilon)^{1/N - 1} \cdot g'(\epsilon)
\\ = \frac 1N \det(B)^{1/N}\det(I + \epsilon B^{-1}A)^{1/N - 1} \cdot \operatorname{tr}(B^{-1}A).
$$
Plugging in $\epsilon = 0$ yields $f'(0) = \frac 1N \det(B)^{1/N}\operatorname{tr}(B^{-1}A)$, which leads to the Taylor expansion
$$
f(\sigma_s^2) = \det(B)^{1/N} + \frac 1N \det(B)^{1/N}\operatorname{trace}(B^{-1}A)\sigma_s^2 + O(\sigma_s^4)
$$
that I mentioned in a comment on this question.

Comment: Thanks so much, but is the second term is $\frac 1N  \sigma_s^2 \det(B)^{1/N}\operatorname{trace}(B^{-1}A)$, correct?

Comment: @Andrea Of course. It's funny that I pointed out your mistake when I made the exact same error